# How to get a function to return a string?

Tags: c

How do we return a string from a function?

I'm just beginning to learn to use the string functions and malloc, basically, i'm trying to get:

> ef = 11101111

as an output.

Here's what i've tried.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

const int MAXWORD = 2; 
char hexToBinary(char hex[MAXWORD]);

int main()
{   
char hex[MAXWORD] = {'e','f'};

printf("%s = %s\n", hex, hexToBinary(hex));

return 0;
}

char hexToBinary(char hex[MAXWORD]) 
{
char *hexToBn = malloc( (MAXWORD-1) * sizeof(char) );
char *convertedString = malloc( (MAXWORD-1) * sizeof(char) );

for(int i=0 ; i<MAXWORD ; ++i)
{   
    if(hex[i] == 'e' || hex[i] == 'E')
    {
        strcpy(hexToBn, "1110");
    }
    if(hex[i] == 'f' || hex[i] == 'F')
    {
        strcpy(hexToBn, "1111");
    }

    strcat(convertedString, hexToBn);
}

return convertedString;
}
```

Comment: 1) Use `convertedString = malloc( (MAXWORD * 4 + 1);` 2) `*convertedString = 0`; 3) Other issues

Comment: 3) `char hex[MAXWORD+1] = {'e','f', '\0'};` 4) Other issues

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to make a function that returns a C string, declare it returning `char*`:

```
char *hexToBinary(char hex[MAXWORD]) {
    ...
}
```

This is not ideal, because it creates a possibility of a memory leak. In fact, your code would leak a string, because you never `free` what's allocated in `malloc`.

You should either fix the leak by capturing the return value and calling `free` once you are done with it, or use the buffer+length API pattern:

```
char *bin = hexToBinary(hex);
printf("%s = %s\n", hex, bin);
free(bin);
```

An alternative API would look like this:

```
void hexToBinary(char hex[], char bin[], int len) {
    ... // Users pass the output buffer bin and its length len
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple ways to do so:

1: Allocate string on the heap and pass it to the caller. The caller ensures the string is delete using free.

```
char * get_str()
{
    char * str = malloc(string_length + 1);
    // Do something
    return str;
}
```

2: pass the string to the function

```
void update_string(char * input, int length)
{
     // modify string
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Declare the return type as `char*`. Then use it like you would.

Note: you may have to do other things to your code. I just said the first thing I saw at a glance. Also, you need to make sure that your memory is deallocated with `free` when you are done with it.